# What is the name of the song/piece playing in Full Metal Alchemist episode 6 at 6:48?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

In *Full Metal Alchemist* (2003) episode 6 at 6:48, there's a song playing. What is the name of this piece?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's Despicable Acts of the Fullmetal Alchemist OST